# compare specific days in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am in the process of making an attendance program and after finding the two matches for a particular ID number, which is being collected by a google form, I would like to confirm the fact that the user did not accidentally sign in/out by comparing just the day of the two time stamps and making sure they are the same. I have been finding ways to compare using milliseconds from unix's start date, but not a way to plainly do it by date. Could someone please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the date of a timestamp and leave of the times you can use something like this to generate just dates or just times.

```
function messinWithTime()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    rngA[i][1]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(rngA[i][0]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy");
    rngA[i][2]=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(rngA[i][0]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss");
  }
  rng.setValues(rngA);
}
```

This is my sheet with just timestamps from a linked sheet:

[image]

This is my sheet after converting timestamps to separate dates and times.

[image]

## Appending data to daily sheets

I think this will do it for you.

Code.gs:

```
function movinToDailySheets()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Responses');
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
  var rg0A=rg0.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<rg0A.length;i++)
  {
    if(!rg0A[i][4])
    {
      var destSheet=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(rg0A[i][0]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMM dd, yyyy");
      if(!isSheet(destSheet) )
      {
        var destSht=ss.insertSheet(destSheet);
      }
      destSht.appendRow(rg0A[i]);
      sh0.getRange(i+1,5).setValue('Done');
    }
  }
}

function isSheet(name)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets=ss.getSheets();
  var r=false; 
  for(var i=0;i<allsheets.length;i++)
  {
    if(name==allsheets[i].getName())
    {
      r=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

This the my starting spreadsheet.  I added a column at the end called "Completed" so that when this functions runs again it will not appended old data to the sheets.

[image]

This is what the spreadsheet looks like after running the code.

[image]

These are the sheets that were created.

[image]

And each sheet had data. This is the Aug 1, 2017 data.

[image]

Comment: However, I cant compare these as just dates. If i try and compare using a ===, it will still take the other variables into consideration.

Comment: Most of the time I'm just interested in establishing that a pair of dates represent the same day and in that case running them through formatDate like I have will work just fine. Personally, I don't use === very often.  Mostly I use ==.

Comment: how are you obtaining the value of the individual cells in the script? Ive been using sheet.getRange(1,3).getValue();

Comment: getDataRange() and getValues() gets all of the data on the sheet and I created the sheet with 3 header titles and 1 column of data then went through each row calculating date only in column 2 and time only in column 3

Comment: Okay, but what I want to know is what is the script you are using for the actual comparison after sorting the timestamps. Thanks

Comment: Tell me more about what your trying to accomplish and perhaps I can make up a script example for you.

Comment: So I want to be able to organize data collected by a form into different sheets that are sorted by day. Like I want to be able to open a sheet marked Aug. 3. 2017 and then it will have all the entries. The issue I am having is trying to sort the time stamps by date. Thanks again for your time

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet without sharing private information?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mMc-MnzoQZpLOW3l-noCB_0e8o9kRg_oCSI53LF__R4/edit?usp=sharing Here you go

Comment: In regard to Your question regarding sorting the timestamps.  The timestamps don't need to be sorted in a form response sheet because they are already sorted in that they just represent the date and time of the response submission. Most recent appended to the bottom.

Comment: not in the sense of sorting the time stamps in that sheet. I would like to sort out the sheet in the sense of trying to figure out which ID numbers were logged in during a certain day and then migrating that data into another sheet.

Comment: Well the id numbers are now spread into the sheets for each day.  Is that what you want?

Comment: i dont see any changes

Comment: I don't understand what changes are you expecting and where would I find them?

Comment: Oh I suppose that you expected to see changes to your spreadsheet.  I just copied the data and did it on my side and the functions are in the answer now.